# Uber Eats API scopes

Tags: uber-api, pos

I'm following the Uber Eats API documentation and i'm having trouble with it. I want it to work with my point of sale web app.

The documentation say:

> To generate a client credentials token, retrieve your client_id and client_secret for your app from the developer dashboard...

But when trying to generate client credentials it shows:

> Sorry, Can't generate an access token, make sure you have checked at least one scope which is allowed to generate access token using client credentials.

But there are no items available for selection in the developers dashboard.

Documentation: https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/guides/authentication#example-request

Dashboard: https://developer.uber.com/dashboard/

Comment: Do you have any news?

Comment: Are you able to share how you got the NDA and test accounts?

Answer (score 0):

You have to contact the person who provided the accounts to activate them. I think only they can do it.

Comment: How do you contact this person to begin with btw?